# Display serious of numbers under same column in excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I want to display a serious of numbers in same column in excel sheet

```
-30,
-25,
-20,
-15,
-10,
-5,
0,
5,
10,
15,
20,
25,
30,
```

Excel is throuwing error to create function to do this. The formulas I tried is not working.

[image]

Comment: If you start by - sign Excel will think that it's a formula. If you want it to treat it as text, put ' in front of the text ('-30). It will not be visible.

Comment: I tested the input `-30,` and there was no error. as it looks right now, Sijith tried to crate a real formula which is just not working (tough he hasn't included it to the question which would help)

Comment: Thanks boss, its working

Answer (score 0):

In **A1** enter:

```
=(ROW()-1)*5-30 & ","
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: @DirkReichel.........it's just the way I think...........I usually set the constant in a formula like this to be the first value I want displayed.........a simple mental crutch.........

Comment: @DirkReichel  .........I admit that both your suggestion are slightly better than mine because they each have a single subtraction and a single multiplication.

Comment: wasn't for something like that... just the question for doing it two times. still your approach is perfect when doing it like: `=(ROW()-ROW($A$1)*5-30 & ","` while $A$1 needs to be changed to the first cell used (the -30) ;)